# can't zoom UIWebView for certain web pages

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiwebview

Why are there a view web pages when shown in UIWebView that are zoomable and some not? How do I make all of them zoomable? I can zoom for a few pages, but not all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some pages are configured with special meta tags that tell webkit 'I've rendered this content for mobile.  Don't scale it'.

If you view such a page, there is no way to enable zooming through UIWebView.  The content is saying "I'm already scaled!" and UIWebView will refuse to scale it further.

Edit:  To answer the second question (above was 'why', now for 'how do I make it happen anyway'):  You can't, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set scalesPageToFit to YES on the webview.  See the documentation...

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

"If YES, the webpage is scaled to fit and the user can zoom in and zoom out. If NO, user zooming is disabled. The default value is NO."

Comment: It is set to YES and I can zoom on a few pages, but not all websites.

Comment: Can you zoom on these pages from mobile safari?